# IE8 Javascript behavior

Tags: javascript

wonder if anyone can help.

Bascially I'm working on a site, and a chunk of functionlity works great in all browsers apart from ie8. It doesn't throw an error as such. Just doesn't behave correctly.

Bascially here; http://new.jda.co.uk/?page_id=12

if you click on any of those companies - it should bring up a lightbox which has a xml/javascript populated carousel relevant to the company clicked. In ie8 it just throws up the one company every time.

Any thoughts? I'm not fantastic at browser/javascript debugging so I'm struggling to get to the bottom of this.

Thanks

I have looked a bit more into this; and it seems the js file is loading fine, the xml file is being written correctly - but when it comes to the parsexml function - it seems to be hanging onto the same set of data regradless of what you click;

```
function parsexml(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","write.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


}
```

As far as I can see this narrows it down to this section not reading in and updating the latest file - does the ie8 browser interpret this code differently somehow ?

Also I just checked the actual write.xml file on the server...this updates every time. If I browse to the file ie8 - it doesn't update. If I close the browser and fire up try again, it updates to the saved file !

Comment: Seems to work with IE 8.0.6001.18702. Do you happen to have MultipleIEs or similar installed?

Comment: I confirm it's buggy with 8.0.7600. Can you tell which frameworks are you using ?

Comment: I'll have to mention that I have the developer tools installed on IE 8. It may be a reason why it works for me e.g. the console.log is defined.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Jquery, it's a custom wordpress theme, and I'm grabbing the company name, grabbing relevant company "info" from the wp db, sticking that into XML with PHP then reading that back into a Javascript array when it comes to the mediabox firing up, then I populate the jquery carousel with the array.

Comment: I'm on ie9 as default - using virtual PC for ie8. But the bug was spotted on someone elses machine running ie8 as default.

Comment: I'll add that the XML is fine - I checked the contents every time I click and it's writing the correct data into the file. somehow it's reading that same data every time. Almost like the array isn't being refreshed or cached.

Comment: I looked at your code and it's hard to tell where the data is passed to the box. Can you tell where is the click handler or anything relevant? Anyway, beware of you IDs, there are supposed to be unique, and some libraries assume they are. I highly encourage you not to use them this way, I had in the past faced issues because of them not used uniquely.

Comment: when you click a company, the casestudies_fbox.php page is called which (in a php fucntions) creates the write.xml page. the casestudies page is called with javascript up into a lightbox via an id on the link. Once the media box is loaded, the carousel is populated through the js. The JS loads in write.xml and then populates the carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the ID tip I'll look at sorting that as soon as poss.

Comment: I second that note about duplicate "id" values.  That's never a good idea.

Comment: Just noticed the actual JS file loads up in every browser apart from ie8 for some reason (well doesn't fire an alert("loaded") up anyhow.

Comment: IDs *must* be unique. Ignoring this basic rule will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: The js file does seem to be loading :( must be something else - I'll look into imporving the ID's see if that clears things up.

Comment: Probably Cache issue - the file `write.xml` is being cached in the XMLHttpRequest somehow. Not sure it will work, but try calling `xmlhttp.open("GET","write.xml?randNumberHere",false);` where `randNumberHere` is some random number you generate.

Comment: Hi, Shadow Wizard - thanks ! this has fixed it, very grateful. I actually used a slightly different line after you pointed me in the right direction. Not sure if it makes a difference. The date approach only seems to be the difference. var url = "write.xml?RandomKey=" + Math.random() * Date.parse(new Date()); If you post your comments up as an answer I can mark it up as accepted - if that's how it works.Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @fraz sorry for late reply, without Envelope didn't see your comment, you can use `@` to send notification to the inbox e.g. `@Shadow` - posted answer now, please also edit your question with what you done for the sake of those facing similar problem who don't go through all the comments here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Cache issue - the file write.xml is being cached in the XMLHttpRequest somehow.

Try having:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","write.xml?randNumberHere",false);
```

Where `randNumberHere` is some random number you generate.